# Flex: streaming video from YouTube

Tags: apache-flex, youtube, video-streaming

Is it possible to use the VideoPlayer or VideoDisplay components in Flex 4 to stream a video from YouTube rather than just use the custom YouTube player? How?

I want to serve a video inside a banner.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible from what I know.  If you really want your own video in a banner, why not put the video up on your own server instead of using Google's?

Comment: You like answering beside the question I see. :)
I am already doing that but as I've heard Google might have slightly better CDN around the world then my own single solitary small tiny server.

Comment: And you like asking fairly obvious questions.

Comment: Well, if they were obvious (to me, to be humble) i wouldn't have asked then. But hey, thanks for all those letters you typed.